# How can I access redirect url from keycloak inside Docker container with cy.Visit()?

Tags: yaml, cypress, drone.io

**State:**

I've got an application, that is built with **Angular** (as Front-End) and **Quarkus** as (Back-End).
The application first redirects the user to KeyCloak, and redirects back to the application (does not matter if online or localhosted) after a successful login.

For CI/CD I use **Drone CI**. Drone builds the applications first and runs the application in the container, but instead of localhost it has a customized url, lets call it app-url.

For End-To-End Testing I use **Cypress**. The test I want to do is a login test. There are no other npm packages, only cypress and newman in this project. Locally the test can be executed successfully, it makes 2 requests, 1 for authentification and 1 for getting the redirect url which is needed to access the content inside the application.

Here is the test in code that works on localhost:

```
describe('simple login test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.clearCookies();
        cy.clearLocalStorage();

    });

    it('login', () => {

        cy.log('login start')

        function createUUID() {
            const s = [];
            const hexDigits = '0123456789abcdef';

            for (let i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
                s[i] = hexDigits.substr(Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x10), 1);
            }

            s[14] = '4';
            s[19] = hexDigits.substr((parseInt(s[19]) & 0x3) | 0x8, 1);
            s[8] = s[13] = s[18] = s[23] = '-';

            return s.join('');
        }

        cy.request({
            url: '{keycloak-url}',
            qs: {
                client_id: '{clientid}',
                redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8360',
                scope: 'openid',
                state: createUUID(),
                nonce: createUUID(),
                response_type: 'code',
                response_mode: 'fragment',
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            cy.log('login first request')

            const _el = document.createElement('html');
            _el.innerHTML = response.body;

            const loginForm = _el.getElementsByTagName('form');
            const isAlreadyLoggedIn = !loginForm.length;
            if (isAlreadyLoggedIn) {
                return;
            }

            cy.wait(1000)
            cy.request({
                form: true,
                method: 'POST',
                url: loginForm[0].action,
                followRedirect: false,
                body: {
                    username: "user",
                    password: "pwd"
                }
            })
                .then((res) => {
                    cy.log('login second request')
                    cy.log(res);
                    cy.wait(1000)
                    cy.log("RedirectToUrl ist " + res.redirectedToUrl)
                    cy.visit(res.redirectedToUrl);
                    cy.log('Login Redirect complete')
                })
          })
     });
})
```

**Error:**

The error is with the redirect uri. Cypress does make an attempt to command a visit but everytime, the redirect cannot be accessed with Cy.Visit().

```
https://app-url:8360/

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:
  &gt; Error: connect ECONNREFUSED {ip for app-url}:8443

Common situations why this would fail:

  - you don&apos;t have internet access
      - you forgot to run / boot your web server
      - your web server isn&apos;t accessible
      - you have weird network configuration settings on your computer" type="CypressError"><![CDATA[CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:
    
    https://app-url:8443/
    We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.
    We received this error at the network level:
      > Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.208.6:8443
    Common situations why this would fail:
      - you don't have internet access
      - you forgot to run / boot your web server
      - your web server isn't accessible
      - you have weird network configuration settings on your computer
        at http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:138876:23
        at visitFailedByErr (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:138235:12)
        at http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:138875:11
        at tryCatcher (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:10791:23)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8726:31)
        at Promise._settlePromise (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8783:18)
        at Promise._settlePromise0 (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8828:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8904:18)
        at _drainQueueStep (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:5498:12)
        at _drainQueue (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:5491:9)
        at Async.../../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js.Async._drainQueues (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:5507:5)
        at Async.drainQueues (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:5377:14)
    From Your Spec Code:
        at Context.eval (http://app-url:8080/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/tests/simple-login.spec.js:162:12)   
    From Node.js Internals:
      Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.208.6:8443
          at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
      ]]></failure>
        </testcase>
      </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
```

This is the yml with the steps for drone:

```
- name: test ui
    image: image for test ui
    volumes:
      - name: cypress_results
        path: app/cypress/results
      - name: cypress_screenshots
        path: app/cypress/screenshots
      - name: cypress_videos
        path: app/cypress/videos
    commands:
      - ./docker/app/wait-for.sh http://app-url:8360/ --> Bash file that makes drone wait until that url can be reached
      - cd test
      - npm install
      - npx cypress run --config baseUrl=http://app-url:8360/ --spec "cypress/integration/**/*" --env testuser=user,testuserpw=pwd
```

**Attempts to solve the problem:**

1. Checked ports, even changed ports to match them
2. Removed cy.visit(), which leads to a pass
3. Checked for correct Cypress Version
4. Checked in KeyCloak for the redirection url.
5. Project tested locally with CLI. Test could also be executed successfully
6. Internet connection has been established with a bridge in docker compose
7. Checked for availability of the website. In the yml file you can see the marking for a bash file which makes drone wait until the website has been established

**Question:**
Are there any workarounds? If yes, what will it be? Has it to do with the container itself?